# is the wind from shaytaan or is it an actual fart?

Tags: salat, wudu, prayer-timings, waswasa

before i did suffer from waswas and i dont know if i still exactly do. this haappened recently but i am trying to improve even thouh i still go throught it sometimes, i usually do wudu for every prayer (dueto discharge) and during prayer my body becomes anxious and i feel tense because i feel like wind is going to come but as soon as i do salam my body calms down and i feel no pressure for wind. sometime during my tense feeling in salah i feel like i let out wind came out even tho i didnt exactly feel like the pressure or it just doesnt feel like a normal fart so sometme i re do my wudu or i either dont and iif i dont i feel guilty because i feel like the wind was a real fart.

duing my asr i was praying and i was pretty this time and so i suddently felt anxious and felt a wind (like fart) but it wasnt as if i let it out (i just felt it on its own), but i did not re do my wudu. i know that i felt it but i dont know if its exacly wind or if its shaytaan playing tricks. deep down i feel like i should re do my prayer and wudu but at the same time i disnt want, please help me. i feel guilty but also like a bad person as if i am not re doing it because i am looking for excuse.

what do i do? i want to re do it but i dont know if its shaytaan trap? but at the same time i dont want to because i am tired of having to keep on doing wudu everytime and feel like i should because i did feel it?

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu Alaikum and Praise be to Allah,
What you are experiencing is waaswas from Shaytaan trying to distract you in prayer. Seek refuge in Allah (swt) when that happens. Also, do not stop your prayer unless you are sure you know some wind has come out. You also should make sure you always recite the prayer with meaning and focus in on meaning of prayer as prayer is the highest level of iman and most important part of the religion